# eliminating rows with opposing values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to eliminate rows with opposing values for example
I have the following rows in my table

```
id     value1  value2  value3
----   ------  ------  -------
10     -1        -20     -48.5
10      1         20      48.5
10     -1        -30     -26.2
10      1         30      26.2
10      1         27      30.5
```

what I would like to get is

```
id     value1  value2  value3
----   ------  ------  -------
10      1         27      30.5
```

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if you had two rows like `1,20,48.5` and only one like  `-1,-20,-48.5`?

Comment: Funny that none has tried set methods.... EXCEPT. Assuming value 1,2,3 are identical just negative filtering first by positive and removing all having a matching negative sound like native SQL approach (albeit except / intersect are quite new)

Answer (score 0):

I'm returning positive numbers. Then I group all the fields, returning only single-line ones. You can use `MIN` or `MAX` in select. Both will return the correct result.

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (id INT, value1 INT, value2 INT, value3 FLOAT)

INSERT INTO @Tbl        
VALUES 
(10,     -1,        -20,     -48.5),
(10,      1,         20,      48.5),
(10,     -1,        -30,     -26.2),
(10,      1,         30,      26.2),
(10,      1,         27,      30.5)


SELECT
    T.id ,
    MIN(T.value1) ,
    MIN(T.value2),
    MIN(T.value3)
FROM
    @Tbl T
GROUP BY
    T.id ,
    ABS(T.value1) ,
    ABS(T.value2),
    ABS(T.value3) HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
```

Result:

```
id  value1  value2  value3
10  1       27      30.5
```

I recommend you test it on bigger data. You may have performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
    id INT,
    value1 INT,
    value2 INT,
    value3 DECIMAL(9,2)
)

INSERT @T VALUES
(10, -1, -20, -48.5),
(10, 1, 20, 48.5),
(10, 1, -20, -48.5),
(10, -1, 20, 48.5),
(10, -1, -30, -26.2),
(10, 1, 30, 26.2),
(10, 1, 27, 30.5)

SELECT A.* FROM @T A
LEFT JOIN @T B ON
    B.id = A.id
    AND B.value1 = -A.value1
    AND B.value2 = -A.value2
    AND B.value3 = -A.value3
WHERE B.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
Compare the Table to itself to look for opposite values.
You can achieve that by multiplying the value of the second table by -1, looking for the opposite.
Since you did not specified if all or some of the values have to be opposites, i assumed they all must be opposites, and that's why I use AND in the JOIN.
If the condition is met just by any value, then change the AND by OR in the JOIN.
*/

DECLARE     @MyTable    TABLE   (id int, value1 int, value2 int, value3 numeric(5,1))
INSERT INTO @MyTable    VALUES
            (10, -1, -20, -48.5)
        ,   (10,  1,  20,  48.5)
        ,   (10, -1, -30, -26.2)
        ,   (10,  1,  30,  26.2)
        ,   (10,  1,  27,  30.5)
;

SELECT          T1.*

FROM            @MyTable    T1
    LEFT JOIN   @MyTable    T2  ON  (T2.value1 = -1 * T1.value1)
                                AND (T2.value2 = -1 * T1.value2)
                                AND (T2.value3 = -1 * T1.value3)
WHERE   T2.id   IS NULL
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to exclude (delete) the rows with opposites, a solution is make a CTE to get all these records and delete them:

```
drop table if exists #a
create table #a (id int, value1 INT, value2 INT, value3 FLOAT)
INSERT INTO #a
VALUES 
(10,     -1,        -20,     -48.5),
(10,      1,         20,      48.5),
(10,     -1,        -30,     -26.2),
(10,      1,         30,      26.2),
(10,      1,         27,      30.5)

;with duplicateRows as (
    select a1.id
    from #a a1
    where exists ( --Verify the results with opposites
        select * from #a a2
        where
            a1.id = a2.id
            and a1.value1 = - a2.value1
            and a1.value2 = - a2.value2
            and a1.value3 = - a2.value3
        )
    )
delete duplicateRows --> Make a select first for test!

select * from #a --> The row of value2 = 27 is the only one now
```

Comment: He does not say delete - he says eliminate. Like from query results.